# "Cannot assign requested address": when host name is provided in google oauth LocalServerReceiver.Builder() parameter

Tags: java, oauth, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am getting **Cannot assign requested address** Exception every time when  host name is provided in the `LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setHost(host_name)` while authenticating google service using Oauth2 .

```
// Build the local server and bind it to port 8080
LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder()
                     .setHost(host_name_not_localhost)
                     .setPort(8080)
                     .build();
```

Comment: Something else is already bound/listening on port 8080.  You can start by finding out what process is listening on port 8080 before you call that code.

Comment: I have tried removing the port from the call but still getting the same error @JoakimErdfelt .